# Python Unit testing for While Loops

Tags: python, unit-testing, while-loop

I'm trying to figure out how I would go about creating a test suite for a while loop that outputs a basic string. I have a pretty basic countdown timer, and I just want to test it to see if it works properly. I've done unit test before, but never for loops. Below is the code I'm trying to test. I just want to be able to get the 'OK' back. Thank you in advance for all the help!

```
import time

timer = 11

while timer > 0:
        timer = timer - 1
        print(timer)
        time.sleep(1)

print("Times up!")
```

Comment: What do you want to compare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not understand what exactly you want to compare to determine whether the test has failed or passed. But if you are looking for the unit test snippet, then here you go

A very crude way to check it

```
import unittest
import time

expectedOutput = range(5)
class UnitTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_while(self):
        # Put your code here.
        timer = 5
        while timer > 0:
            timer = timer - 1 
            self.assertTrue(timer == expectedOutput[timer])

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(UnitTest)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Comment: Hey So i would want to check the system output. So to check if the while loop is doing the countdown if that makes sense. So essentially I would be checking the timer on each iteration. @dilip

Comment: thank you very much. In short its for a system that will teach students how to program functions like these. So for example I would say "Hey create a timer variable that countsdown" thus I would check if they implemented it correctly using the test suite. @dilip